# Upload FileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, detect

I'm working on a project in which I have to upload `.txt` files. I'm using asp.net FileUpload. Here is a piece of code:

```
<div class="custom-file">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="inputFileTXT" CssClass="custom-file-input" runat="server" />
    <label id="lblFileName" runat="server" class="custom-file-label" for="inputFileTXT">Elegir archivo</label>
</div>``
```

I'm using styles from MDBootstrap.

The thing is that I want to do stuff when a user clicks on the `asp:fileUpload` element and selects a file **WITHOUT CLICKING ON A BUTTON**. I've been searching but I didn't find how to detect dynamically this action. The `asp:fileUpload` has no event such as `OnUploading`.

PD: I tried using an UpdatePanel but when it makes the postback it seems like the uploaded file disapears. Maybe this is the way but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Maybe the lostfocus even could be a solution?

Comment: you want to detect on client side?

Comment: Yes, I want to detect on client side, in the moment the user selects his file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a dummy LinkButton to the page and leave it empty, but give it an `OnClick`, in which you would process the file.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" accept="image/*" />

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then in code behind add the `onchange` trigger to the FileUpload control that will do a PostBack of LinkButton1.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileUpload1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "__doPostBack('" + LinkButton1.UniqueID + "','')");
}
```

PS do not put a FileUpload Control in an UpdatePanel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I'm a bit lost.
"FileUpload1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "__doPostBack('" + LinkButton1.UniqueID + "','')");"

What I'm supposed to do with that? I've never worked with triggers.

Comment: You add it to the Page_Load of the page. It add's the `onchange` event to trigger a click that has the same result as clicking on `LinkButton1`

Answer (score 0):

You want to detect when a file is assigned to the upload just use `change` event.

Jquery solution:

```
$('#inputFileTXT').on('change', function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

javascript solution:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="inputFileTXT" CssClass="custom-file-input" runat="server" onchange="doStuff(this);" />

function doStuff(control){
    //do stuff
}
```

You can then read files by using `FileReader api` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

and access files using `.files`:

```
var files = $('#inputFileTxt').files;
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to use 'runat="server"' in mi asp:fileUpload because there's logic on the server's side. I need the file to be loaded to, then, make stuffs with it. I read it and fill a datagridview with the data stored in the .txt file.

Comment: ok, so you want to post to the server as soon as the user selects a file - automatically without them needing to button click then, correct? If that's the case then just do what @VDWWD has said in the other answer.

Comment: Yes. The idea is to let the server knows when a file is upload without pressing a button.

Comment: I've edited my comment, the answer with the link button will do that for you

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filename?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_FileUpload_FileName) link

You should get the file details in `FileUpload1` (fileUpload control Id: inputFileTXT in your case).